# Distinct value of a column and do a count on each distinct value

Tags: excel

Hi I have a column like this. [image: Column]

I know how to count the number of distinct value of this column, but I also want to do a count on what is the number of different distinct value.Is there an easy way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What constitutes a distinctive value? Would  `DL` alone be distictive or would `DL CHK SV` all together constitute one distinctive value?

Comment: Everything in a cell constitutes a distinctive value.

Comment: Still confused.. Is the entire first cell, for example `DL CHK SV` a distinctive value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the following example:

[image]

To get the unique values, and the occurrences of each unique value, you can do the following:
[image]

The image is tiny, so here is are the formulas to type-in and drag down:

**FORMULAS**

**1. Type in the first cell of column B:**

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$8),0,0),0))),"",INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$8),0,0),0)))`

Drag the formula down the column B. You will get a list of unique values.

**2. Type in the first cell of column C:**

`=COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,B2)`

Drag the formula down the column C. You will get the number of occurrences of each unique value.

**RESULT**

This is what you will get:

[image]

Comment: Hi Mariam, Sorry to didn't explain it clearly. What I meant was, the whole text string in of that column is considered to be one value. in your example, I would say e.g 'AA BB CC, DD EE FF, GG HH II' is 1 value.

Comment: That's what I understood! So my answer above is based on that. Does that work for you?

Comment: Let's taking your table as example. The result I want to get is: AA BB CC (3) Since it occurred 3 times. AA BB CC, DD EE FF, GG HH II and AA BB CC, DD EE FF, GG HH JJ both count 1 because they only occur once. Then, AA BB, FF GG, XX, YY, ZZ(2) because it occurred twice. Hope your understand me better..

Comment: Yes, but I also want to do a count on each distinct value,like how many times does each distinct value occurs in this column

Comment: Ohhh got it! Let me modify my answer then.

Comment: Thanks.:)  I will leave my desk a while. Will be back ASAP

Comment: Check modified answer above!

Comment: What I don't like about Filtering is that it is very "manual", you can't reproduce it easily for a huge number of columns/files. But the above formula is not complex, it is just a bit long to deal with #N/As.