# Find all unique values in column then count occurances

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in excel with many different model types. There are about 100. Each occurs randomly a different amount of time in the column. I have found a similar question but it seems like I need to list all unique values first. As of now I am filtering and counting the total.

I would like the output to look something like

```
Model   |       Occurance

A |99

B| 47

C|55
```

A link that had a similar question is here: [Distinct value of a column and do a count on each distinct value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639096/distinct-value-of-a-column-and-do-a-count-on-each-distinct-value) yet it is not a perfect fit.

Comment: Have you tried using a Pivot Table? It would be as simple as creating the Pivot table based off your data, putting the column you want to get the distinct values from in the "Rows" area, then putting the same column in the "Data" area and having it do a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let your `Model` data be at `A2:A100` range and your `Occurance` data be at `B2:B100` range

1) You can use following array formula (I've got it from this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470475366)) to find unique values (note that it works only if your data doesn't contains empty rows). Select destination range (for example `F2:F100`) and then enter the following formula in the formula bar:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$100,SMALL(IF(MATCH($A$2:$A$100,$A$2:$A$100,0)=ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS($A$2:$A$100))),MATCH($A$2:$A$100,$A$2:$A$100,0),""),ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & ROWS($A$2:$A$100))))),"")
```

and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it.

2) next step, write following formula in `G2` and stretch it down until `G100` :

```
=IF(F2<>"",SUMIF($A$2:$A$100,F2,$B$2:$B$100),"")
```

it will give you total occurance for each value

Comment: Hmm, looks promising but it did not work for me. I will claim operator error for this one :p! I made a dummy file with A2:A20 three different names randomly occuring. I then pasted these formulas in but when I stretched step 2 formula I got "FALSE". Thanks simoco and rep to you anyways :)

Comment: It looks like it is just picking the first unique value and arraying it down in correspinging rows___ while leaving other cells blank