# Sum of values in column for each value in adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I have some data on number of pages printed which is basically a row for each print job with username and number of pages. I want a total of pages for each user.

my data looks like this:

```
COL1   COL2
dave   2
john   3
dave   1
sally  5
sally  1
john   2
dave   4
ben    8
```

and I want to end up with:

```
COL1   COL2
dave   7
john   5
sally  6
ben    8
```

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095341/find-all-unique-values-in-column-then-count-occurances/21095647#21095647) could help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all unique values in column then count occurances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21095341/find-all-unique-values-in-column-then-count-occurances)

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMIF(COL1:COL1,"dave",COL2:COL2)
```

Note that doing it this way will require you to enter each name individually when counting. Watch out for circular reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pivot tables. It's exactly made for analysis as you describe. Pivot tables is a builtin feature in Excel and a quite powerful analysis tool.

Start with selecting your data to be analyzed and then make a pivot table out of that data.